# Chrome issue with javascript fixed by clearing history/cache...how did it happen in first place?

Tags: javascript

I have had 2 customers have an issue where an errorL jquery is undefined. Once I clear their cache/history and then reload the pages; it works fine.

I use cache busting so that shouldn't be an issue (all.js?VERSION=XXX) if they had an older version from before.

I am NOT using a CDN; but I am combining scripts together using yui compressor.

What things can I look for? NOTE: I cannot reproduce this on my browsers.

I load the javascript in the head of the document (as one ; and I have some scripts in the body of the document.

Note sure this will help but here is js:
https://demo.phppointofsale.com/js/all.js

Comment: Pretty hard to say without seeing how your scripts are loaded.

Comment: Do you have any JS that uses jQuery outside of `all.js`?  Could be that for whatever reason `all.js` didn't load (the internet isn't perfect), but the rest of the code continued to (try to) run

Comment: Yes I have scripts outside of all.js; but the odd part is the system is installed on localhost. As I said as soon as a clear cache it works fine.

Comment: It's always a good idea to load JQuery first, before loading any other script. It sounds like a strange timing issue. But for starters make sure Jquery is loaded first in your html.

Comment: It is the first script.